# remote SSH root login with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: server, ssh, vpn

I'm pretty much a novice with Ubuntu, still exploring.

I have a VPS server. I was able to set-up two PPTP VPNs with Ubuntu 11.04 but now I'd like to try my hand at an IPSEC/L2TP connection. However, logging into the server is an issue.

With Ubuntu 11.04, in terminal, I do:
ssh root@IPADDRESS
and enter the password. Voila.

BUT with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I cannot. It does not work.
I set the root password with the VPS control panel so it should be working... any help?
This is what I'm trying to get to: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_12.04.html

Answer (score 5):

Does your Ubuntu 12.04 box allow the `root` account login via `ssh`? By default, Ubuntu doesn't allow the `root` account to do `ssh`.

Enabling the root account to access ssh directly is a major security risk. However, you can enable it if you like to do so by doing the steps below:

1. Edit the sshd_config file by `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Find the line `PermitRootLogin no` and change it to `PermitRootLogin yes`.
3. Restart the ssh service by `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart` or `sudo service ssh restart`

You have now enabled ssh using the root account.

Comment: Root should already be activated as the guys at the VPS service indicated without giving me much more clues as to what to do:

"I am able to access the server via port 22 without any issues. Please do verify the below snippet.

=======
[root@llocalhost ~]# ssh root@80.83.121.146
root@80.83.121.146's password:

[root@llocalhost ~]#"